# Indent code inside brackets with regex

Tags: regex, string, tabs, indentation

I would like to indent a code string with tabulation. The simple rule is that I must append a tabulation after each line feed inside braces "{}".

My trouble is for nested braces... here I need many tabulation to be exactly the number of nested braces.

Do you think it is possible to do with a regex replace?

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible with to be done with regex [at least with standard regex, which stand for regular expressions for [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)] because the language you are describing is irregular!

It is even impossible to know if there are the same number of `{` as `}` in a given string with regular language.

We can show that if this language is regular, using [homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism#Homomorphisms_and_e-free_homomorphisms_in_formal_language_theory) we can create the language `L={anbn}` which is a known irregular language.